# gqlgen API returning HTML instead of JSON

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, next.js13

I've written a gqlgen API that works fine in the GraphiQL browser tool. I'm able to run queries and mutations without a problem in the browser, but when I try to connect to the API from an external source using the URL the request returns the raw HTML of the GraphiQL web interface.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you need to `POST` to this api. If you do a `GET` then you'll end up with the GraphiQL UI.

Comment: I'm using nextjs with Apollo Client and everything works fine when I use a public route and it's only giving me an error when I change the URL to my gqlgen URL. Changing  the URL shouldn't change the method of the request made to the api.

Comment: It shouldn't but if you're getting raw html back that tells me you're doing a GET